# How to style inside of map in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have `pluck` and `map` methods that parse some data:

```
<%= @driver.cars.pluck(:name, :purchase_date).map{ |c| c[0] + ' on ' + c[1].strftime('%d.%m.%Y') + ' at ' + c[1].strftime('%H:%M') }.to_sentence %>
```

How do I change the color just for the name part of the data in `c[0]`?

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
.map{ |c| <span style="color: blue;">c[0]</span> + ' on ' + c[1].strftime('%d.%m.%Y') + " at " + c[1].strftime('%H:%M') }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to spit out that code in an ERB view - they don't work quite the same as React (which I'm guessing is perhaps what you're familiar with based on your examples): you want to iterate through a collection with `each`, not `map` - something like this, perhaps:

```
<% @driver.cars.pluck(:name, :purchase_date).each do |car| %>
  <span style="color: blue;"><%= car[0] %></span>
  on <%= car[1].strftime('%d.%m.%Y') %>
  at <%= car[1].strftime('%H:%M') %>
<% end %>
```

The [Rails documentation on ERB / templates](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_view_overview.html#templates)  is really excellent - it might help you understand what's going on under the hood a bit better.

If you're dead set on using `to_sentence`, there's [a view helper](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper/to_sentence) that makes things slightly easier to deal with:

```
<%=
  to_sentence(
    @driver.cars.pluck(:name, :purchase_date).map do |car|
      raw(
        <<~HTML
          <span style="color: blue;">#{car[0]}</span>
          on #{car[1].strftime('%d.%m.%Y')}
          at #{car[1].strftime('%H:%M')}
        HTML
      )
    end
  )
%>
```

Comment: It looks like `map` was used initially to return an array to be used by `to_sentence`.

Comment: You're totally right about the React thing but in this case I have to keep the map just for using to_sentence (in case of one car you solved the problem, but in case of many cars I'd lose the "and" that to_sentence gives). Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: @Commando I've added another example of how you could use to_sentence in that context, if you're dead set on using that helper method.